# Why does a post request to update steam avatar not work?

Tags: python, post, request, steam-web-api

im trying to upload a new avatar with a post request to this [site](https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader?type=player_avatar_image&sId=STEAM64ID)*, but it doesn't work. I tried to mimic the request i did when i uploaded the file via google chrome, but also nothing happens.
Here is the code

```py
import requests

r = requests.post(
    url='https://steamcommunity.com/actions/FileUploader?type=player_avatar_image&sId=STEAM64ID',
    files=
        {
            'file': open('test.png', 'rb')
        },
    cookies=
        {
            'sessionid': '',            #Left blank for privacy reasons
            'steamLoginSecure': '',   
            'steamCountry': '',
            'browserid': ''
        }
)

print(r.cookies)
```

When i run the code, this is the output

```py
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Shouldn't it print the cookies i sent?

*`sId=Your steam64id`

Comment: Does Steam have API documentation on this? You might want to check that. Also is the API token / key correct? Should you use forms?

Comment: It doesn't use Steam's API. The auth key is the `steamLoginSecure`. And i just want to send in a POST request with a file attached to it.

Comment: Unless you provide links of documentation on Steam you most likely won't get helpful answers. Please provide more info about the action.

Comment: I have searched github and found [this](https://github.com/Leystryku/steamavatarchange/blob/master/src/main.cpp). It's what i wanted to do. Sadly, im not very good with curl and I dont quite understand the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this action supposed to be completed by a human via a browser? If so, Steam might have measures in place that prevents your program / robots from using this action.

The server most likely expects session data, specific cookie headers, a human user agent, and more so that robots will not be able to upload.

EDIT:

Check the [robots.txt](https://steamcommunity.com/robots.txt):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /actions/
Disallow: /linkfilter/
Disallow: /tradeoffer/
Disallow: /trade/
Disallow: /email/
Host: steamcommunity.com
```

You are clearly not allowed to use the /actions/ route with your program and Steam enforces this rule.